# OpenSSH Server Windows 10 - How to configure for private key based authentication?

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I'm trying to configure OpenSSH on Windows 10 Pro for private key based authentication.

I'd like a client to be able to authenticate based on a private key only, without entering a password.

I stumbled across threads that mention the Authentication Agent (what is it actually doing?) and command lines tools like ssh-add.exe (where does it add what to?) and ssh-keygen.exe etc. I played with it but I just don't see any results.

Can anyone explain the required actions, step by step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a comprehensive description here:
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/ssh.exe-examples

Following these steps solved the problem for me.